# Marketing cloud extend <a> tag to space or punctuation after tag is closed in emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I'm having a consistent problem with emails sent via Marketing Cloud. We use the classic content builder and HTML paste for newsletters. We have a problem where some links get extended to include the space or punctuation immediately after them or extra spaces are added, even though those characters are outside the closing tag.

For instance

```
...swiftest <a style="color: #035781;" href="https://www.example.org/">refugee outflow</a> after...
```

shows up in my inbox as

```
...swiftest <a style="color: #035781;" href="https://www.example.org/">refugee outflow </a>after...
```

And I can't figure out why. The same thing sometimes happens with commas and periods, where a space is added between the end of the text and the comma (which is outside the link). It doesn't happen on all links, just a handful, but it consistently happens across all the emails we send. These links show up correctly in the preview within marketing cloud, but appear incorrectly in email clients from both test and real sends.

I was told by my predecessor that this is a known Marketing Cloud bug and we can't do anything about it, but I can't find anything about that online. Has anyone encountered this or know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Update:

It appears that removing inline styles from the A tag fixes the issue. Without the style above it shows up correctly, but with the link extends into the extra space. However I still don't know why this is happening.

Comment: What email client(s) are showing this issue?  This could be an email client issue, not a SFMC issue if it is not happening universally on all email clients.

Comment: @Gortonington good thought, thank you. I just sent a test to Email on Acid, which provides screenshots of your email in a bunch of different clients, to check. The extra space shows up on every configuration of mobile/desktop/web client they test so it seems like it's coming from marketing cloud.

Comment: I have not been able to replicate your issue - even in an email with 20 different links inside of it.  Can you share the code?  Barring that, I would recommend taking the links out and pasting them into an empty email and seeing if the behavior is  potentially caused by styles/meta tags/etc instead of the actual A tag.

Comment: @Gortonington Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it. How do people usually share a chunk of code on stack exchange? Also I'd be happy to share the code with you personally, but I feel a little weird about posting it publicly. Is that allowed? I'm new to stack exchange and don't really know the rules.

I ran out of space for a comment so I updated the post above with more details about how inline styles seem to be causing this.

Comment: This answer gives great instruction on posting code in SFMC: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks.  There are many that post the entire relevant code into a question, but if you are uncomfortable that is completely understandable. The bit about inline styling may be enough for now - I will investigate that.

Comment: Sorry but I still am having issues replicating this issue.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy for posting this. I ran into the same issue and it was maddening. For me, it was between link text and commas, and only on 2 out of 13 links. Even with the inline-block fix (thanks @erick) it still happened on one link and we had to sacrifice an Oxford comma for it.

Comment: Hi Amber, good to know I wasn't the only person struggling with this but unfortunately I can't help -- we ended up just moving away from marketing cloud (which fixed that and a number of other problems!)

Answer (score 2):

@Jeremy

I'm facing the same issue too, although not consistently (some hyperlinked text didn't have the extra space, and this is within the same EDM).

Adding `display: inline-block` to the problematic `<a>` tags seems to solve the problem. No extended space or whatsoever.

Comment: This helped me with this incredibly frustrating bug. Thanks!

Comment: Not working for me, when there's punctuation after the link.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue for links preceding punctuation, which was inconsistent between email clients. I tried adding display:inline-block to the `<a>` tag, but for longer text in the `<a>` tag it created other formatting issues.

So to fix this, I added `<span style="display:inline-block;">[punctuation here]</span>&nbsp;`

eg. Start of sentence `<a href="#">link text</a><span style="display:inline-block;">,</span>&nbsp;`further sentence text.

The `&nbsp;` was necessary, because without it there was a spacing issue after the punctuation!

Hope this can help someone else with this frustrating bug.

Comment: Not working for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure there are no spaces at:

`<a href="HERE">HERE</a>HERE.`